# How to solve the problem with memory size in R?

Tags: r

I took the below error while trying to create data set in rstudio

`Error: cannot allocate vector of size 19.9 Gb`

Then I tried to check and change the memory size by using this code:

```
> memory.size()
[1] Inf
Warning message:
'memory.size()' is Windows-specific 

> memory.limit()
[1] Inf
Warning message:
'memory.limit()' is Windows-specific
```

how I can solve the problem.
It is worthfully to say that the mentioned approache is also tested in ubuntu that the result was the same.

Comment: As the help page for the function explains, it is only applicable for windows machines.

Comment: Thank you @Phil. is there any way to solve the problem in Linux?